# dvc push certificate verify fail for gcp

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, terminal, push, dvc

Trying to push data into a bucket in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) from Visual Studio via `dvc push`
ERROR:
[image]

Tried:

> `gcloud auth login`
> `gcloud auth application-default login`
> `gsutil ls`
> `pip install dvc[gs]`

And I am in the corresponding project and bucket in gcp. Problem after: `Querying 1 oids via object_exists`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you already checked this [github issue](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/7148)?

Comment: Solved by running file: /Applications/Python 3.9/Install Certificates.command following the github issue provided by @MarcAnthonyB. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Posting the solution as a community wiki to help other community members who will encounter this issue.

This was solved by regenerating the certificate using [Python Certifi](https://appdividend.com/2022/06/01/python-certifi/). To do so, run `Install Certificates.command`. In @MLB9 's case, the script was under **/Applications/Python 3.9/**.

Executes the script:

```
/Applications/Python 3.9/Install Certificates.command
```

---

More information at this [Github issue](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/7148).